# How do run await in background in window phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to run a method on background when app is closed.

```
async private void()
{
    var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgw.DoWork += (s,v) =>
    {
       string temp= await doSomething();
    };
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,v) =>
    {
       //...
    };
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

It produces the following error

> the await operator can only be used within an async lambda expression.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`DoWork` cannot be `async`. I recommend you use `Task.Run` instead:

```
async private void X()
{
  await Task.Run(() => doSomething());
  //...
}
```

However, you may need to call `Wait` instead of `await` since this is done at application shutdown.